# How to send data to CloudFlare API?

Tags: php, guzzle, cloudflare

I'm trying to delete files from my CloudFlare cache using PHP. Using Guzzle I've done this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->delete('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myzoneid/purge_cache', [
    'query' => [
        'files' => 'https://example.com/styles.css,
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'X-Auth-Email' => 'myemail',
        'X-Auth-Key' => 'myapikey',
    ],
]);
```

But when I run this I get an error:

> Client error: `DELETE https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myzoneid/purge_cache?files=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/etc` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":1012,"message":"Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\", \"files\", \"tags\" (truncated...)

I can't get it to work using Postman either. I put in the required headers and try to set a key of `files` or `files[]` with the URL but it doesn't work. I've also tried `data` with raw JSON as the value like `{"files":["url"]}` (along with a JSON content-type header) but get the same error. It thinks I'm not sending the `files` key.

Comment: Try changing `'files' => 'https://example.com/styles.css,` to:

`'files' => ['https://example.com/styles.css'],`

Ref: https://github.com/jamesryanbell/cloudflare/blob/master/src/CloudFlare/Zone/Cache.php#L35

Comment: @mishka Yes I've tried that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The method for purge_cache is POST instead of DELETE (Source: https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url).
- The payload is not sent as 'query', but as 'json'.
- Files should be an array, not a string.

So the correct syntax should be....

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->post('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myzoneid/purge_cache', [
    'json' => [
        'files' => ['https://example.com/styles.css'],
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'X-Auth-Email' => 'myemail',
        'X-Auth-Key' => 'myapikey',
    ],
]);
```